# Simplify (using the laws of Boolean algebra)

Tags: boolean-algebra

I have:
$(\overline{A} \land \overline{B} \land \overline{C}) \lor (\overline{A} \land \overline{B} \land C) \lor (\overline{A} \land B \land C) \lor (A \land \overline{B} \land \overline{C}) \lor (A \land B \land \overline{C}) \lor (A \land B \land C)$

I found this (step by step) solution:

1. $(\overline{A} \land \overline{B} \land \overline{C}) \lor (\overline{A} \land \overline{B} \land C) \lor (\overline{A} \land B \land C) \lor (A \land \overline{B} \land \overline{C}) \lor (A \land B \land \overline{C}) \lor (A \land B \land C)$
2. $(\overline{A} \land \overline{B}) \lor (\overline{A} \land B \land C) \lor (A \land \overline{B} \land \overline{C}) \lor (A \land B \land \overline{C}) \lor (A \land B \land C)$
3. $(\overline{A} \land \overline{B}) \lor (\overline{A} \land C) \lor (A \land \overline{B} \land \overline{C}) \lor (A \land B \land \overline{C}) \lor (A \land B \land C)$
4. $(\overline{A} \land C) \lor (\overline{B} \land \overline{C}) \lor (A \land B \land \overline{C}) \lor (A \land B \land C)$
5. $(\overline{A} \land C) \lor (A \land \overline{C}) \lor ( \overline{B} \land \overline{C}) \lor (A \land B \land C)$
6. $(A \land \overline{C}) \lor (B \land C) \lor ( \overline{A} \land \overline{B})$

What rule is used here to absorb variables?

1) $(\overline{A} \land \overline{B} \land \overline{C}) \lor (\overline{A} \land \overline{B} \land C) \Leftrightarrow (\overline{A} \land \overline{B})$

2) $(\overline{A} \land \overline{B}) \lor (\overline{A} \land B \land C) \Leftrightarrow (\overline{A} \land \overline{B}) \lor (\overline{A} \land C)$

3) $(\overline{A} \land \overline{B}) \lor (\overline{A} \land C) \lor (A \land \overline{B} \land \overline{C}) \Leftrightarrow (\overline{A} \land C) \lor (\overline{B} \land \overline{C})$

Can you show an example of how to do this?

Comment: The reference "here" in "What rule is used..." is not clear.  Are you asking about one of the *steps* or all of them?  When you ask for "an example of how to do this", the reference to "this" is similarly unclear.

Comment: For example, about: $(\overline{A} \land \overline{B} \land \overline{C}) \lor (\overline{A} \land \overline{B} \land C) \Leftrightarrow (\overline{A} \land \overline{B})$

Comment: In that case, we have, by using the distributive property, $\Big((\overline{A} \land \overline{B})\land (\overline C \lor C)\Big) \iff (\overline A \land \overline B)$.  Now what do you know about $(\overline C \lor C)$.

Comment: @amWhy $(\overline C \lor C) \equiv 1$

Comment: Also, $\Big((\overline{A} \land \overline{B}) \land 1\Big) \iff (\overline A \land \overline B)$

Comment: Exactly. So on the left-hand side we have $$\overline A \land \overline B \land 1 \equiv  \overline A \land \overline B$$  $P \equiv P\lor 1$

Comment: Can I use this same for:
$(\overline{A} \land \overline{B}) \lor (\overline{A} \land B \land C) \Leftrightarrow (\overline{A} \land \overline{B}) \lor (\overline{A} \land C)$ 

 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) $\def\neg#1{\overline{#1}} (\neg{A} \land \neg{B} \land \neg{C}) \lor (\neg{A} \land \neg{B} \land C) \iff (\neg{A} \land \neg{B})$

$$\begin{split}  (\neg{A} \land \neg{B} \land \neg{C}) \lor (\neg{A} \land \neg{B} \land C) \iff & (\neg A\land \neg B)\land(\neg C\lor C) &:\text{distribution, and association}\\ \iff & (\neg A\land \neg B)\land\top &:\text{complementation/tautology}\\ \iff & \neg A\land \neg B &:\text{identity}\end{split}$$

> 2) $(\neg{A} \land \neg{B}) \lor (\neg{A} \land B \land C) \iff (\neg{A} \land \neg{B}) \lor (\neg{A} \land C)$

Use the above, and idempotence.   Sometimes making things seem more complicated helps to simplify them.

$$\begin{split}(\neg{A} \land \neg{B}) \lor (\neg{A} \land B \land C) 
& \iff (\neg A\land\neg B\land \neg C)\lor (\neg A\land\neg B\land C)\lor (\neg A\land B\land C)
\\ & \iff (\neg A\land\neg B\land \neg C)\lor (\neg A\land\neg B\land C)\lor (\neg A\land\neg B\land C)\lor (\neg A\land B\land C)
\\ & \iff (\neg{A} \land \neg{B}) \lor (\neg{A} \land C)\end{split}$$

> 3) $(\neg{A} \land \neg{B}) \lor (\neg{A} \land C) \lor (A \land \neg{B} \land \neg{C}) \iff (\neg{A} \land C) \lor (\neg{B} \land \neg{C})$

Do you have the idea, now?   Give it a whirl.